# Sorting logs in json-file by timestamp

Tags: python

I have two json-files with logs in format:

```
{'log_level': 'INFO', 'timestamp': '2021-11-13 13:07:00', 'message': 'Farnsworth ate a fish in L.A. day before yesterday'}
{'log_level': 'INFO', 'timestamp': '2021-11-13 13:02:27', 'message': 'Fry played a fish near the Square Garden day before yesterday'}
```

I want to sort them by 'timestamp' in ascending order. But I can't.
I tried this:

```
merged_list = []
    for strings in jsonl_file:
        result = json.loads(strings)
        merged_list.append(result)
        merged_list.sort(key=lambda x: time.mktime(time.strftime(x['timestamp', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'])))
```

And this:

```
s = sorted(merged_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['timestamp', '%Y-%m-%d']))
```

I even tried using regex, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code snippet to sort a list of dictionary by timestamp.

```
from operator import itemgetter
merged_list.sort(key=itemgetter('timestamp'), reverse=True)
```